# Presto/SQL variable length character data with an optional maximum length

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I came across queries in a project I inherited, here I noticed an optional parameter passed after the data type in cast (4)

```
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON SUBSTRING(CAST(t2.list_id AS VARCHAR(4)), 1, 4) = SUBSTRING(CAST(t1.list_id AS VARCHAR(4)), 1, 4)
```

I then found this https://prestodb.io/docs/current/language/types.html where it mentions this is **Variable length character data with an optional maximum length**. I then did further testing to try and determine what this optional parameter actually does and found no difference in the output using the following 2 queries

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(list_id AS VARCHAR(4)), 1, 4) AS convertedLID,
    list_id
FROM "db"."table1";

SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(list_id AS VARCHAR), 1, 4) AS convertedLID,
    list_id
FROM "db"."table1";
```

Can someone please explain to me what the optional cast parameter does?

Comment: Actually as far as I understand it already truncates the data - try out `select cast('12345' as varchar(4));`

Comment: Presto/Trino and MySQL are different SQL dialects, removed the corresponding tag.

Comment: Yes this returns 1234 as expected select cast('12345' as varchar(4)); but the field I am trying to run this does not get truncated which is unexpected, type is bigint? I then tried on a string type field and it truncates? And what I am gathering, if it actually worked, I could use either the additional cast parameter or the subtr to achieve the same thing but both not necessary?

Comment: Interesting findings. I would argue that `VARCHAR(4)` in the original query does not have any hidden meaning and was done possibly just from pure habit maybe by someone coming from another SQL dialect.